# Google Spreadsheet trick

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, match, lookup

Here is sheet 1: [image]

Here is sheet 2: [image]

From a Google Spreadsheet, each time I have a ticker/symbol from sheet 2 which is also in sheet 1, I want to copy and paste the line from sheet 1 into sheet 3. Here is a test spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxljIY-lm5P-pTssKlRAQoyozdb_fhADhpIfUvWkdqo/edit?usp=sharing. Do I have to build a macro or I can use the `FILTER()` and `LOOKUP()`function? How can I do that easily?

Comment: Access denied [You can't access](https://i.imgur.com/IYhjpfd.png), Please [share everyone](https://i.imgur.com/Oh4SUnW.gifv), Note that your email addess is visible to anyone who accessed the sheet.

Comment: @Osm It should be fine now

Comment: what is the range of the first line in sheet1?

Comment: Is this [sample result](https://imgur.com/a/vNyL3i0) the result you want to see on your **Sheet 3**? Based on your **Sheet 2** data from a column named `Ticker`, only _MU_ & _XOM_ has matches on your **Sheet 1** from a column named `to`. Is this the actual process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(Sheet2!A2:I, COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet2!A2:A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula** in `Sheet3!A1`

```
={"Symbol"; Sheet2!A2:A}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure it really helps me. I have a column named Ticker in sheet 2. Each time one of those ticker is also in the column called Symbol in Sheet one, then I want to kinda print or copy and paste the line associated with the symbol from sheet 1 to sheet 3. Am I express myself well?

Comment: Please clarify wich symbol, the cell named symbol? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!A2:A, COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet2!A2:A))),
                  Sheet1!A2:J,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},0))
```